# Is it healthy for newborn puppies to live on direct land?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, parasites, cleaning

My dog Jamie (no breed) had 4 puppies on July 8th. They haven't opened their eyes as of yet.

Prior to this,
Jamie dug a hole in the ground in the yard and there she gave birth to her puppies.

While it's true that in the hole they are 'safe' so that my other dog (boxer of 5 years) can not hurt them, I think it is not healthy for the puppies that live there.

Today I took one of them out of the hole and I realized that the puppy had 3 pebbles in its mouth, and I took them out. The puppies are directly in contact with the land and hence they practically breathe nothing but dirt, I mean they get no fresh air.

My question is: Is it healthy that puppies live there? Could puppies get an allergy because of being in the dirt constantly?

Should I take them out and 'build' them a little house (so they would be in a cleaner place) and where they would be protected as well?

Should I leave them in the hole?

If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a lot like how wolves and other wild canids build a den

While this is 'natural' behaviour - you're almost certainly going to be better off setting up a dedicated, indoor area. Puppies tend to get in trouble, they're at risk from outdoor critters - both insects and other, larger threats and it gives them better opportunities to socialise with people.

Your dog's clearly acting on her instincts but moving them indoors is probably a great idea. You're probably looking for something like a [whelping box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whelping_box).

As with many situations like this - you might want to have a word with your vet about the best course of action to take

Comment: she had shown wolves behaviour before, she liked to wallow with corpses when she had the opportunity. But I think you're right, I should call the vet too. Thanks!